# JNA: What's the most efficient way to do Windows process read/writes?

Tags: java, windows, jna

I am looking for the most efficient way to do Windows process reads/writes with JNA.

I use the following two methods to accomplish this:

```
public static Memory readMemory(Pointer process, long address, int bytesToRead) {
    Memory memory = new Memory(bytesToRead);
    KERNEL32.ReadProcessMemory(process, address, memory, bytesToRead, 0);
    return memory;
}

public static void writeMemory(Pointer process, long address, Memory memory) {
    KERNEL32.WriteProcessMemory(process, address, memory, (int) memory.size(), 0);
}
```

I would much rather use something like `ByteBuffer` that I can re-use to avoid garbage creation. Is it possible to re-use JNA's `Memory` in a similar way?

As far as `Memory` goes, what does `index` mean in:

`void write(long offset, byte[] buf, int index, int length)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadProcessMemory REALLY Slow In JNA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776620/kernel32-instance-readprocessmemory-really-slow-in-jna)